# how to publish an app that will work on iOS 3.2 as well as use the app-suspending-and-going-to-background feature on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, suspend

My app does not use any of iOS 4 APIs but all I want it to do on iOS4 is that it should go to the suspended state after the user presses the home key. When I install the app to iPhone 4 using device 3.2 as the base SDK, the app is not suspended when the user presses the home button. i.e. the next time user launches the app, the app does not remember its old state.. Whereas, when I run the same app with devide 4.1 as the base SDK, it does remember its state.

Now, I want to submit my app for publishing to the app store. How can I submit such that it will work on iOS 3.2 as well as use the suspending feature on iPhone 4? or can I submit two versions, one for iOS 3.2 and other for 4.0 or more?

Thanks,
Ashish.

Comment: You can submit 2 different Apps, one for iOS 4.0 and above, and other for iOS 3.2 and below... but they cannot have the same App name. Otherwise you will have to search around stackoverflow and look for well explained ways to make App run on different iOSes.

Comment: Just set the deployment target to 3.2 and set the base sdk to 4.2. It will get suspend/resume in iOS 4.0+ and it will run fine on 3.2. Just make sure you don't call any non-3.2 methods or properties, etc. without checking them, or that will crash the app in a 3.2 environment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your info.plist file
2. Add The Key UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend(for below 4.0 sdk) or Select Application does not run in background(for  4.0 or higher sdk)
3. Set the new key to YES (for below 4.0)or Fill in the tick box(for  4.0 or higher sdk)

Now your applicationwillterminate: method will be run when the user taps the home key, and your app will exit for real.

Comment: @Ashish, Use only one option.its depend on your sdk. This will work fine for 4.0 or greater than this.

Answer (score 0):

check the ios version inside your code and depending on the version enable and disable the functionality. Search stackoverflow/google. This has been answered.